# Join two mysql SELECT queries with the same id

Tags: mysql, join

I have two SELECT queries:

```
SELECT a.id, a.prev_task 
FROM s_task_assignment a
```

and

```
SELECT d.id, a.first_name, a.last_name 
FROM s_users a, s_task_assignment d 
WHERE a.id = d.responsible_id
```

they have one same column - `a.prev_task` and `d.id`. This columns contains an id.

So I need somehow join results of this two queries where `a.prev_task = d.id` but I do not know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put in into **one query** like:

```
SELECT a.id, a.prev_task, d.id, b.first_name, b.last_name 
FROM s_task_assignment a, s_users b, s_task_assignment d 
WHERE a.prev_task = d.prev_task AND b.id = d.responsible_id
```

So we renamed the `a` in the second query to `b`, and furthermore we added the table of the first query to the `FROM` clause and added the `a.prev_task = d.prev_task` filter.

You can however make it syntactically more elegant by using `JOIN` statements, like:

```
SELECT a.id, a.prev_task, d.id, b.first_name, b.last_name 
FROM s_users b
     JOIN s_task_assignment d ON b.id = d.responsible_id
     JOIN s_task_assignment a ON a.prev_task = d.prev_task
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

I made a mistake in my second query, it must be:

`SELECT d.id, a.first_name, a.last_name FROM s_users a, s_task_assignment d WHERE a.id = d.responsible_id`

I've corrected it and your answer helped me to solve my problem!

Comment: @Kir: please [`[edit]`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43277351/edit) your question.

Comment: I've corrected my question. Thanks a lot once more.